# pyspark group and split dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to filter and then split a dataset into two separate files.

Dataset: test.txt (Schema: uid, prod, score)

```
1   XYZ 2.0
2   ABC 0.5
1   PQR 1.0
2   XYZ 2.1
3   PQR 0.5
1   ABC 0.5
```

First, I want to filter any uid having less than or equal to 1 product. I have already achieved that by the following code.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

rdd = sc.textFile('test.txt').map(lambda row: row.split('\t'))
schema = StructType([
           StructField('uid', IntegerType(), True),
           StructField('prod', StringType(), True),
           StructField('score', FloatType(), True)])
df = rdd.toDF([f.name for f in schema.fields])
filtered = df.groupby('uid').count().withColumnRenamed("count", "n").filter("n >= 2")
all_data = df.join(filtered, df.uid == filtered.uid , 'inner').drop(filtered.uid).drop(filtered.n)
all_data.show()
```

This produces the following output:

```
+----+-----+---+
|prod|score|uid|
+----+-----+---+
| XYZ|  2.0|  1|
| PQR|  1.0|  1|
| ABC|  0.5|  1|
| ABC|  0.5|  2|
| XYZ|  2.1|  2|
+----+-----+---+
```

I need to now create 2 files out of the above dataframe. The problem that I am now facing is what is the best way to take one row for each product (can be any row) and put it in a different file(val.txt) and the rest of the rows in a different file (train.txt).

Expected output (train.txt)

```
1    XYZ    2.0
1    PQR    1.0
2    ABC    0.5
```

Expected output (val.txt)

```
1    ABC    0.5
2    XYZ    2.1
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I think the key issue here is that you don't have a primary key for your data.

```
all_data = all_data.withColumn(
    'id',
    monotonically_increasing_id()
)

train = all_data.dropDuplicates(['prod'])

# could OOM if your dataset is too big
# consider BloomFilter if so
all_id = {row['id'] for row in all_data.select('id').collect()}
train_id = {row['id'] for row in train.select('id').collect()}
val_id = all_id - train_id

val = all_data.where(col(id).isin(val_id))
```

Comment: This will randomly split the entire dataset. But I need to take only row of each uid and put it in the "val" file while the rest of the rows of each user in the "train" file. The number of rows each user can have can vary.